# fetching data and upsert into database

Tags: postgresql, go

I want to get data from api and then doing query into specific tables using upsert, for example :

**Repository**

```
   // get data from api
   response, resErr := http.Get("look at json that want to fetch")
   if resErr != nil {
      fmt.Print(resErr.Error())
    return resErr
    }

    // Read response from the API
    defer response.Body.Close()
    responseOdoo, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    //unmarshaling data to struct
    var responseObject []models.OdooResponse
    json.Unmarshal(responseOdoo, &responseObject)
```

here I want to perform an upsert to an existing table, but I don't know how to combine the data that has been retrieved and then fill it into the query

```
// get data from table and then upsert into column
qapi := `
insert into services_new 
    (code, service_id, service_name, service_category_id, service_category, service_type_id, service_type , price, request_type, status, uom_code, created_at , created_by, created_by_name, updated_at, updated_by, updated_by_name)
    values
        ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,NOW(),$12,$13,NOW(),$12,$13)
    on conflict (service_id, service_category_id, service_type_id)
do update set service_name =excluded.service_name, service_category =excluded.service_category, service_type =excluded.service_type, price =excluded.price, request_type =excluded.request_type, status =excluded.status, uom_code =exluded.uom_code, created_at =excluded.created_at, created_by =excluded.created_by, created_by_name =excluded.created_by_name;  
`
_, sqlErr := tx.ExecContext(ctx, qapi, request.Code, request.ServiceID, request.ServiceName, request.ServiceCategoryID, request.ServiceCategory, request.ServiceTypeID, request.ServiceType, request.Price, request.RequestType, request.Status, request.UomCode, helper.Fullname, helper.Email)

// checking query upsert services_new
if sqlErr != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    log.Println("sql Error on Repository Upsert on ODOO Services", sqlErr)
    return sqlErr
}

txErr = tx.Commit()
if txErr != nil {
    return txErr
}
return nil
```

until here, is the flow correct?

**JSON That want to fetch**

```
        {
            "service_id": 1129,
            "service_name": "Adobe Illustrator",
            "service_category_id": 28,
            "service_category_name": "License Software",
            "service_type_id": 25,
            "service_type_name": "Software",
            "create_date": "2020-03-09 03:47:44"
        },
```

**struct models**

```
type UpsertFromOdooServices struct {
    Code              string    `json:"code"`
    ServiceID         uint      `json:"service_id"`
    ServiceName       string    `json:"service_name"`
    ServiceCategoryID uint      `json:"service_category_id"`
    ServiceCategory   uint      `json:"service_category"`
    ServiceTypeID     uint      `json:"service_type_id"`
    ServiceType       string    `json:"service_type"`
    Price             float64   `json:"price"`
    RequestType       string    `json:"request_type"`
    Status            string    `json:"status"`
    UomCode           string    `json:"uom_code"`
    CreatedAt         time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    CreatedBy         string    `json:"created_by"`
    CreatedByName     string    `json:"created_by_name"`
    UpdatedAt         time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    UpdatedBy         string    `json:"updated_by"`
    UpdatedByName     string    `json:"updated_by_name"`
}

type OdooResponse struct {
    ServiceID           uint   `json:"service_id"`
    ServiceName         string `json:"service_name"`
    ServiceCategoryID   uint   `json:"service_category_id"`
    ServiceCatrgoryName string `json:"service_category_name"`
    ServiceTypeID       uint   `json:"service_type_id"`
    ServiceTypeName     string `json:"service_type_name"`
    Response            []UpsertFromOdooServices
}
```

Comment: The question needs some clarifications. For example: what is the query language, is it SQL or something else? And which database? Is it postgres?

Comment: yes postgres @ipinak

Comment: Where do these `excluded` come from? `do update set service_name =excluded.service_name, service_category =excluded.service_category, service_type =excluded.service_type, price =excluded.price, request_type =excluded.request_type, status =excluded.status, uom_code =exluded.uom_code, created_at =excluded.created_at, created_by =excluded.created_by, created_by_name =excluded.created_by_name;`

Comment: Do you get an error when executing this query?

Comment: I executed successfully @ipinak

Comment: @ipinak `excluded` is a special table that can be used to reference values originally proposed for insertion ([spec](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)). So that query is fine as is.